# Distribution theory problem

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I need some help with this problem related with distributions:

With $\cal{D}(\Omega)$ we denote de set of the functions of class $C^{\infty}$ in $\Omega$ and compact support.

Let N=3. We consider $\Phi\in \cal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, with $\Phi(0,0,0)=0$. Let $\psi,\phi,$ and $\varphi$ in $\cal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, with $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi=1$. Show that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}(n^3\phi(nx)\psi(ny)\varphi(nz)\Phi(-x,-y,-z)-\Phi(x,y,z))\;dx\,dy\,dz=0$$

Thanks a lot for any help.

***Edited***. *The correct statement is*: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}n^3\phi(nx)\psi(ny)\varphi(nz)(\Phi(-x,-y,-z)-\Phi(x,y,z))\;dx\,dy\,dz=0$$

Comment: As stated this is not true. Probably you mean something else invoking a $\lim_n$??

Comment: The statement may be incorrect, yes. Do you think it is true adding the limit?

Comment: The value of the integral of the first summand is 1. So what else do you want to know?

Comment: This is strange. That would mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\Phi$ would be zero for any $\Phi\in \cal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, which is false...the statement must be wrong. I will ask about it and correct it in case it is.

Comment: Ok, the statement was incorrect. I have just edited it. Now it's ok.

Comment: I don't think it is correct now. I think the limit is $-\int\Phi$, or more generally, $\Phi(0)-\int\Phi$.

Comment: Have you perhaps misplaced a parenthesis, and want $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} n^3\phi(nx)\psi(ny)\varphi(nz)\Bigl(\Phi(-x,-y,-z) - \Phi(x,y,z)\Bigr)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ instead?

Comment: I asked my teacher about it, and it says the statement is now correct...

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman The statement cannot be correct: You still have a first summand (depending on $n$) converging to $\Phi(0,0,0)$ by the argument in Davide's answer (do you understand this?). And the second summand (*not* depending on $n$) is simply $\int\Phi$.

Comment: I dont't see clearly how to use that dominated convergence argument. Once this is justified, I understand changing the limit with the integral leads to the result.

Comment: The first summand equals $\int_{R^3} \phi(x')\psi(y')\varphi(z')\Phi(-x'/n,-y'/n,-z'/n) dx'dy'dz'$ and this converges to $\Phi(0,0,0)$ as the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $|\phi\psi\varphi|\sup|\Phi|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** define $x':=nx$, $y':=ny$ and $z':=nz$, and use a dominated convergence argument.

Comment: I'm almost sure what the OP wants to prove is wrong. $n^3 \phi(nx)\psi(ny)\varphi(nz) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)} \delta$, unless I'm totally off base.

Comment: But here we don't check the convergence in $\cal D'$, just for test function _which vanish at $0$_ (otherwise you are right, it wouldn't be true).

Comment: Ah, I guess you read what the OP meant. There's a misplaced parenthesis then, as written the limit is $\Phi(0) - \int\Phi$, since only the $\Phi(-x,-y,-z)$ is multiplied with $n^3\phi(nx)\psi(ny)\varphi(nz)$. If the integrand were $n^3\phi(nx)\psi(ny)\varphi(nz)\Bigl(\Phi(-x,-y,-z)-\Phi(x,y,z)\Bigr)$, you'd get $0$ - but you wouldn't need $\Phi(0) = 0$ then. Hmm.

Comment: Can anybody detail this a bit? I'm getting a bit confused...

Comment: @Mark_Hoffman Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I think so. I just posted and answer, because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I am correct:

First, with the change of variable you indicated (which has jacobian $\frac{1}{n^3}$), we get that our expression becomes: $\int_{R^3} \phi(x')\psi(y')\varphi(z')(\Phi(-x'/n,-y'/n,-z'/n)-\Phi(x'/n,y'/n,z'/n) )dx'dy'dz'$.

We want to change limit with integral. So have to dominate our integrand by an integrable function, in order to apply dominated convergence theorem. The function $|\phi\psi\varphi|2*sup|\Phi|$ dominates the integrand, and it's integrable, because $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\phi\psi\varphi|2*sup|\Phi|=2*sup|\Phi|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi=2*sup|\Phi|<\infty$, (we could separate the integrals because each one of the three functions depends only on one variable).

Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \phi(x')\psi(y')\varphi(z')(\Phi(-x'/n,-y'/n,-z'/n)-\Phi(x'/n,y'/n,z'/n) )dx'dy'dz'=$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(x')\psi(y')\varphi(z')(\Phi(-x'/n,-y'/n,-z'/n)-\Phi(x'/n,y'/n,z'/n) )dx'dy'dz'=$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\phi(x')\psi(y')\varphi(z')\lim_{n\to\infty}(\Phi(-x'/n,-y'/n,-z'/n)-\Phi(x'/n,y'/n,z'/n) )dx'dy'dz'=$

$=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\phi(x')\psi(y')\varphi(z')((\Phi(-0,0,0)-\Phi(0,0,0) ))=1*(0-0)=0$

Comment: But that is NOT the formula in the OP. Check the paranthesis and the $n^3$-factor. That why we all asked you for the correct formula ...

Comment: I have just edited the question. Yes, I am assuming the correct statement is the one you all said. The other seems to make no sense. 

Is the reasoning I made correct?

Comment: Now, it is correct. But anyhow I would still have a doubt about the question as you don't need the assumption $\Phi(0,0,0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too...I will ask my teacher about this, and if there are news, I will post here. Thanks, Vobo!